# Как сверстать хедер шириной с container?

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать хедер c шириной .container в условиях bootstrap?
Мои варианты:

1. Задать max-width для header равный ширине .container?
2. Сделать обёртку внутри .container и применять стили оформления уже к ней, в то время как header расположен на всю ширину экрана?

Ну не помещать же header в .container..

```css
header {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: container вроде и предназначен для ограничения ширины, почему бы не положить header в .container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<header class="container">
```

И стили выкинуть, кроме фона.